# How is it possible that heat may excite electrons even though it is a continuous energy source?

Tags: atomic-physics

How is it that electrons absorb thermal energy and become electronically excited, given that heat is a continuous source of energy, and electronic energy levels are quantized. I would like to reconcile those two ideas.

Comment: What do you think 'heat' is, and how does it manifest itself in different systems? For example, in solids what we call 'heat' can generally be thought of as lattice vibrations. In a quantum mechanical  treatment, that means we  talk about phonons, quanta of vibration, that have energy and momentum. These can couple to the electrons, so an electron can absorb a phonon, acquiring the energy and momentum. Later, it may re-emit a phonon, all part of exchanging energy between the two subsystems.

Comment: Are you asking about black body radiation? For example why metal glows when you heat it? If so [there are many, many related question on the site already](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=black+body+radiation).

Comment: "These can couple to the electrons, so an electron can absorb a phonon, acquiring the energy and momentum. Later, it may re-emit a phonon, all part of exchanging energy between the two subsystems." This is precisely the process I would like to know more about.

Comment: re-emit a phoTon

Answer (score 1):

> given that heat is a continuous source of energy,

[Heat](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/firlaw.html#c1) is kinetic energy stored in the v[ibrational and rotational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry)) degrees of freedom  of molecules and lattices in liquids and solids, and molecules and atoms in gases.

[Heat is  a classical variable](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/heat.html).

> and electronic energy levels are quantized.

At the quantum mechanical level the atoms and molecules have spill over fields from the quantum mechanical [shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) of the [orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital) of the electrons .  Thus there are positive fields negative fields that set up potentials which create the attractive forces that hold molecules and lattices together.  In quantum mechanical terms these potentials exchange virtual photons while the molecules and the lattices are vibrating .

When the temperature is high enough, and/or at the tail end of the vibrational kinetic energies, the energy needed for a transition of an electron from a lower energy level state to a higher state will become available.

A similar mechanism generates the real photons of [black body radiation,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) from the vibrations and rotations of the atoms and molecules in the samples.

> I would like to reconcile those two ideas.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "spillover fields".  Do you mean *time dependent perturbations* from nearby atoms to  the Hamiltonian of the atom  which can cause a  transitions between its quantized electronic levels?

Comment: @freecharly I am giving a simplified QM picture,  at the level of the  OP. "spillover fields" are the ones causing Van der Waals forces https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force  as well as covalent bonds and ionic bonds . It is because the orbitals are shaped like lego as far as electric fields go, allowing regions of positive and negative electric fields. Even though an atom or molecule is overall neutral , the orbitals allow for shapes in the fields.  To raise the energy of an orbital energy must be changed from kinetic (vibrational) to a photon with an exact atomic energy level.

Comment: @annav I'm sorry to tell you that this is an entirely patronizing and irrelevant response. I am quite familiar with all the concepts you have chosen to discuss in dangerously ambiguous terms. You basically just told me that at high enough temperatures the precise energies the electrons need will become available. How does this pertain to the question? I am inquiring as to the physical mechanism by which this phenomenon may occur. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What you call the "physical mechanism" is ultimately the exchanges of virtual photons, but these are approximated by various models , you can search for book titles in solid state physics. As for the level of the answer, I always answer at the level of the question, if the questioner has not stated his/her physics background, either in the question or the profile, which I look at for new users.

Answer (score 0):

Heat described by classical physics is not discrete and can be described as the infrared region of the electromagnetic spectrum. One example is thermal imaging, which literally detects infrared frequencies. But with quantum mechanics (QM), you can see that electromagnetic waves can be thought as a bunch of photons with certain frequencies. So by QM, heat contains photons of energy with frequency lying in the infrared part of the spectrum. And now that we have the picture of photons we can use them to describe the excitation of electrons by thermal energy.